# iOS Sharing CSV files with UIActivityViewController

Tags: ios8, sharing

I have an app which I share CSV files from, I share other files which work perfectly with both the built in options (such as Mail), and external options such as Gmail app, or Evernote.

If I attempt to share a "CSV" file, the internal Mail option works as expected, however the other options, such as Gmail or Evernote only share the text.  If I rename my CSV file to "pdf" it works in everything also.

Is there a whitelist of allowed file types which can be shared?

My code is faily simple, and looks like this:

```
NSArray* activityItems = [NSArray arrayWithObjects: customItemAttachment, customItemText, nil];
...
UIActivityViewController *activityVC = [[UIActivityViewController alloc]initWithActivityItems:activityItems applicationActivities:nil ];
```

to share:

```
    NSString* fileName = [[BDData sharedData] addDateToFileName:@"DataLog%@.csv"];
    NSData* data = [s dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
    NSString *fileNameLong = [NSTemporaryDirectory() stringByAppendingPathComponent:fileName];
    [data writeToFile:fileNameLong atomically:YES];
    MyShareData* shareData = [MyShareData shareData];
```

If i rename the DataLog.csv to DataLog.pdf, everything "works", its just the wrong extension.

Comment: Did you get solution to this?

Comment: Is there any correlation here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38389014/how-to-share-vcf-file-on-whatsapp-in-ios?

Comment: Nope, it seems there is a whitelist somewhere that allows some types and not others.