# How to share VCF file on whatsapp in ios

Tags: ios, objective-c, whatsapp, uiactivityviewcontroller, vcf-vcard

I am in trouble because I cannot share a VCF file on Whatsapp.

Currently I am using `UIActivityController` for share VCF file on airdrop it is share fine in `iMessage` and Mail but when I am selecting Whatsapp it was not sharing the VCF file.

```
UIActivityViewController *avc = [[UIActivityViewController alloc] initWithActivityItems:@[[NSString stringWithFormat:@“Some Text Here“], URL] applicationActivities:nil];
[avc setValue:@"Sending VCF App" forKey:@"subject”];
avc.excludedActivityTypes = @[UIActivityTypePostToFacebook,UIActivityTypePostToTwitter,UIActivityTypeAssignToContact];
[self.navigationController presentModalViewController:avc animated:YES];
```

Please Help me in this.
Thank you in advance.

Comment: did you get solution for this?

Comment: Could this be related to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31410239/ios-sharing-csv-files-with-uiactivityviewcontroller

Comment: @Skywalker No dear.

Comment: @Skywalker I reserched that time and found that Whatsapp it self first send details to receiver and from details create VCF(Contact file) receiver side. So you can't send VCF directly.